# Passing user and password to Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

this is my scenario: I'm developing a web application where the user logs in, when he clicks a link I want him to be redirected to a Sharepoint site and I want to automatically pass to Sharepoint his username and password, therefore he doesn't need to log in.

How should I do this? Please indicate me the best strategy. I have already tried with this, but it did'nt work out.

http://forums.asp.net/t/883397.aspx

The login via NetworkCredential seems to work fine, but when I redirect my page to Sharepoint it prompts me again for user and password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We did something like this on a application I was working on (although it wasn't a SP site).  You want to setup the web.config so that both site can decode the authentication token (cookie) that is set in your web application.  Take a look at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx) on MSDN that describes how to configure forms authentication across applications.